# New Windows 2008 server on Linux Domain

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, ubuntu, samba

We just installed a Windows 2008 Enterprise server and I'm having a problem joining the domain.  We're running Ubuntu Server, OpenLdap with Samba shares.

Does anyone know of reference material where I can find information about getting this server to properly join our domain.

I've tried googling various boolean searches with poor results.

Comment: Is the server running as an NT4-style domain, or are you emulating Active Directory?

Answer (score 2):

I presume you're using Windows 2008 R2, not plain Windows 2008 - as 2008 should connect to a vanilla Samba server.

http://blog.kenichimaehashi.com/?article=12600130160 should do the trick.

Comment: Also if you have Windows 2008 R2 your Samba version will need to be 3.3 or higher (http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Windows7)

Comment: Upvoted Jon's link